# Dividing the lateral area of a cone into two equal parts.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

"The height of a cone is h. A plane parallel to the base intersects the axis at a certain point. How far from the vertex must this point be if the plane divides the lateral area into two equal parts? If the plane divides the volume into two equal parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Imagine it is a paper cone. Draw a straight line from the vertex to the nearest point on the circumference of the base. Slice along that line, and flatten the cone. We get a circular sector with a certain radius $R$, and area $(1/2)R^2\theta$.

Now for the cone which has half the lateral area, we get circular sector with area $(1/2)r^2\theta$. What is the relationship between $R$ and $r$?

**Another way:** We can do the calculation using more basic facts about scaling. The "half" cone is **similar** to the full cone. If the "half" cone is obtained by aplying the linear scaling factor $k$ to the full cone, then the lateral area of the half-cone is $k^2$ times the lateral area of the full cone. We know that $k^2=1/2$.

Comment: So r=1/sqrt{2}R? Am I right to say 1/2 area A = 2*1/3*pi(rk)^2hk

Comment: For lateral area, our distance from the vertex must be $\frac{h}{\sqrt{2}}$. (It is true that $r=\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}$.) For the same question, except volume halved, scaling linear dimensions by $k$ scales volume by $k^3$. So everywhere we had $\sqrt{2}$ for the area question, we use $\sqrt[3]{2}$.